# How do I implement "perfect forwarding" in a class template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a class template with template parameter T and a member of type T. I want to initialize that member with a parameter passed to the ctor and I also want the passed parameter to be moved if it's a rvalue reference and if T supports move semantic:

```
template <typename T>
class C {
public:
    explicit C(T t) : t_(t)
    {
    }

    explicit C(T&& t) : t_(std::move(t))
    {
    }

    ...

 private:    
    T t_;
 };
```

g++ 4.8 gives the following error if I try to pass rvalue reference to the ctor:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    C<int> p1{x}; // OK
    C<int> p2{1}; // error g++-4.8: call of overloaded ‘C(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous
    return 0;
}
```

The full error text:

```
g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
    main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    main.cpp:23:16: error: call of overloaded ‘C()’ is ambiguous
    C p2{1}; // error g++-4.8: call of overloaded ‘C()’ is ambiguous
              ^
    main.cpp:23:16: note: candidates are:
    main.cpp:12:11: note: C::C(T&&) [with T = int]
      explicit C(T&& t) : t_(std::move(t))
               ^
    main.cpp:8:14: note: C::C(T) [with T = int]
     explicit C(T t) : t_(t)
              ^
    main.cpp:6:7: note: constexpr C::C(const C&)
     class C {
           ^
    main.cpp:6:7: note: constexpr C::C(C&&)
```

Could someone help me, please?
Thanks!

Comment: Just do `explicit C(T t) : t_(std::move(t)) { }`. It's almost perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making the parameter t in C(T t) const reference.

Comment: Try the following: `template< typename T > explicit C(T && t) : t_(std::forward< T >(t)) { ; }`.